# How exactly does Rails fetch data (has_many/belongs_to)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have something like the following:

```
<% if @like = current_user.likes.find_by_post_id(@post.id) %>
```

which is checking to see if a user has liked a post -- What exactly is going on?

My guesses:

1. On page load, Rails pulls all the **IDs of users** who have liked the post and checks if one of those ID's matches the current_user's ID
2. On page load, Rails pulls of the **IDs of posts** the user has liked and does the same thing as #1 above (but in reverse)

Thanks in advance

---

**Question answered by Farley in the comments below.. Something that should've been known but somehow went past my head**

Comment: Check your `log/development.log` and it will show you the SQL query it generates. Also, you can run this from the command line and see that as well.

Comment: @FarleyKnight you're totally right -- `Like Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "Likes".* FROM "Likes" WHERE "Likes"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 2]]`

Comment: It loads the user's likes

Comment: @FarleyKnight, why don't you post your comment as an answer, for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Any SQL engine can do a search with multiple conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id=? and post_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood you should fetch the likes like this

```
<% if @like = current_user.posts.where(post_id: @post.id).likes %>
```

So, it should give you post of the current user where post_id => @post.id and then fetch the likes of that post.